Formal letter greetings
Normally if I am writing a formal letter I'll use the formal greeting,
Estimados señores

I hope thats correct. For this letter I'm wanting to say

Dear Alberto Gomez* and sir or madams at "WHO"*

*, not their real name nor their organisation ""
The following looks okay to me, but I would like someone to check
Estimado Alberto Gomez y señores a "WHO",


‘EStimados señores’ no suena para nada natural. Lo que se dice es directamente ‘estimados’, si se trata de dirigirse a un grupo indeterminado o con muchas personas. En tu caso, incluso ni siquiera es necesario asumir la identidad ni el género de las demás personas: ‘Estimado Alberto Gómez y compañía’.

Gracias, esto esta claro

Well, when you use prepositions, it's not like the same thing in Spanish.
If "Who" is an enterprise (assuming "WHO" is a redacted content), then "a" is not the most appropriate to go there, since "a" in Spanish is not commonly used to refer an enterprise, but to refer to a recipient or a place.
For example:

Dale la carta a Joaquín.

As like you can see, a is used to refer the recipient (Joaquín).
The same thing applies for places you are (for example going to):

Vamos a ir a el centro comercial.

In your sentence, you can say:

If "WHO" is an enterprise:


Estimado Alberto Gomez y señores de "WHO"

Since here we are refering to people who belong to the organization of WHO.

Thank you Estimado Alberto Gomez y señores en "WHO" is an alternativa
